# Android Native Audio development

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to develop the application based on native audio in gingerbread,

I executed the sample native audio program under the NDK ,but I'm not clear with 
that.   I need some example to learn how to use the openSL library.

Can any one suggest an example of open SL|ES based code ?

Comment: thanks for reply Mr phonon,can u suggest me any idea about audio concepts related so it will help full for me to initiate

Answer (score 1):

OpenSL ES [documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/sles/specs/OpenSL_ES_Specification_1.0.1.pdf) and that sample app are the best resources that are out there. Not to say that they're great, but they are definitely sufficient provided that you have the knowledge of object-oriented programming and audio. If you don't, those are the things you should look into first.